# Убрать символ переноса строки

Tags: javascript

Нужно, что бы функция `showSalary` в конце не добавляла перенос строки.

```
let user1 = {
  "balance": "$1,678.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 21,
  "name": "Golden Branch",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

let user2 = {
  "balance": "$1,312.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 24,
  "name": "Ford Billi",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

let user3 = {
  "balance": "$1,553.65",
  "picture": "https://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 20,
  "name": "Rasha Branch",
  "gender": "male",
  "greeting": "Hello, Golden Branch! You have 7 unread messages.",
  "favouriteFruit": "banana"
};

// Массив пользователей
let users = [user1,user2,user3]


//функция 
function showSalary(users, age){
  let resh = []
  users.map(function(item){
    if(item.age <= age){
      resh.push(`${item.name} , ${item.balance}`)
    }
  })
 return resh.join(`\n`);
}

console.log(showSalary(users, 24));
```

Comment: Сделайте проверку, которая будет задавать всем элементам переход на следующую строку, а последнему нет.

Comment: Потестировал... у меня нет перевода строки в конце

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [Array.prototype.join([separator])](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) объединяет массив в строку и ставит `separator` **только между** элементами массива.

Например, если есть массив

```
const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];
```

то после вызова

```
elements.join(`\n`);
```

получится строка `Fire\nAir\nWater`. Таким образом, символа переноса в конце строки не будет.